# Intuition for counting number of pairs

Tags: combinatorics

If we have two groups of $15$ students, how can I intuitively see that the number of ways to pair them is $15!$, if we **DO** consider $(S_i, S_j)$ different from $(S_j, S_i)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line up one of the groups in a row.  Then begin to line up the second group across from the first.  How many students can you place in the first position of the second line?  Having chosen some student, how many ways can you place a student in the second position?  Continue until you've completed the second line.  You should find that there are $15!$ ways to do this.

Now, if we'd like to establish an order on each pair, there are $2$ ways to do this *for each pair*, and thus $2^{15}$ ways to do this for each arrangement of our lines.  Thus, there are $2^{15}\cdot 15!$ such pairings altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Let there are $n$ students. Number them from $1$ to $n$. Choose $1$ and then you can pair him with the rest in $n-1$ different ways. Once you've done that, choose $2$  and you can pair him with the rest (except $1$) in $n-2$ different ways. In this way the total number of pairs you get without taking $(S_i,S_j)$ and $(S_j,S_i)$ same is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\binom{n}{2}$$ So for your case it is $$\binom{15}{2}\ne 15!$$

Comment: Don't you need to take one student from one group and pair him/her with a student from the second group?